# How fast does the function $f(x) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt[\displaystyle{2^n}]{x+2^{n-1}}$ grow in $x$?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, exponential-function, roots, products

### Problem:

The following expression is given:
$$f(x) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt[\displaystyle{2^n}]{x+2^{n-1}} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(x+2^{n-1}\right)^{\displaystyle0.5^n}$$

How fast does it grow in $x$? To be clear, I would like to find good lower and upper bounds $L(x)$ and $U(x)$, such that
$$L(x) << f(x) << U(x)$$
Optimally, an exact growth rate would be the best: $f(x) \sim \Theta(F(x))$ for some $F:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$.

### Used notations:

- If $g(x)$ is a real function, then $\Theta(g(x))$ is a family of functions such that $\forall f(n) \in \Theta(g(n))\;\exists k_{1}>0\;\exists k_{2}>0\;\exists n_{0}\;\forall n>n_{0}\;k_{1}\cdot g(n)\leq f(n)\leq k_{2}\cdot g(n)$
- For real functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$: $f << g$ or $f(x) << g(x)$, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$
- For real functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$: $f \sim g$ or $f(x) \sim g(x)$, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$

### Assumption:

I calculated some values for $f(x)$:

\begin{array} {|r|r|} \hline x & f(x) \\ \hline 0 & 2 \\ \hline 1 & 2.5 \\ \hline 10 & 3 \\ \hline 100 & 4.4 \\ \hline 1000 & 5.9 \\ \hline 10^5 & 9.3 \\ \hline 10^7 & 11.77 \\ \hline  \end{array}

From this it would seem that $f(x) \sim \log_a(x+b) + c$ for some $a,b,c \in \Bbb{R}$. However, I have not been able to find values for $a,b,c$. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try taking logarithms.

$$\begin{align}
L&:=\log\prod_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt[{2^n}]{x+2^{n-1}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}\log\left(x+2^{n-1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}\log\left(2^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{x}{2^{n-1}}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}(n-1)\log2+
\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}\log\left(1+\frac x{2^{n-1}}\right)
\end{align}$$

The first sum can be computed explicitly, and it should be easy to bound the second using the power series for $\log(1+x)$.  Then you have a bound on $e^L$.